# How do you insert non-Cloudant JSON data to dashDB?

Tags: json, bulkinsert, dashdb

How do you insert large quantities of JSON data from a REST API that is not Cloudant into dashDB?

- bjoern

Comment: In the case of Cloudant to dashDB, the JSON data is transformed to relational format. Does that apply to your question? How is the intended format for dashDB?

Comment: While not a REST API, the `db2nosql` command line tool can import JSON documents from a file, to DB2 or dashDB:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1306nosqlforjson2/
Also, there's info on how to use Java/drivers to insert JSON here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/data/libraryview.jsp?search_by=DB2+JSON+capabilities

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Aislinn, Simple Data Pipes is designed to move large quantities of JSON data via REST APIs: [see on GitHub](https://github.com/ibm-cds-labs/pipes) 
At the moment, Version 2 of pipes is coming with a SalesForce and Stripe billing connector that lets you move the data to dashDB.

It also adds a connector API that allows you to easily write your own custom connector.

You can check out a sample connector [here](https://github.com/ibm-cds-labs/pipes/tree/master/connector_templates/SampleConnector2).

This sample connector shows you how to simply move some hard-code json records. You can use it as a starter to build your own.

A complete tutorial is in the works and should be released some time next week.

Comment: It's probably worth stating that you shouldn't do a row-by-row load into dashDB as you will probably not get very good compression.  Instead batch up the data and use an api like  https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/docs/dashdb/rest-api/ to bulk load the data.